# non-complementary alternative hypothesis - what if neither $H_0$ nor $H_1$ are true?

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

In decision making theory in books the null hypothesis $H_0$ is always counterbalanced by the alternative hypothesis $H_1$. The significance level $\alpha$ is defined as the probability of the rejection region given $H_0$: $\alpha=P(R|H_0)$, whereas the power $1-\beta$ as the probability of the rejection region given $H_1$, $1-\beta=P(R|H_1)$. As far as I am understanding to design a good test therefore one has to diminish $\alpha$, keeping the power as big as possible, ideally $\alpha=0$ and $1-\beta=1$.

**Question:** suppose that neither $H_0$ or $H_1$ is true. That is, suppose neither of the models $H_0$ or $H_1$ is true. What control do we have on this situation under this setting?

For example even if $\alpha=0$ and $\beta=1$ if we reject the null hypothesis it seems to me that we can safely say that $H_0$ is not true, because $\alpha=0$ but we cannot conclude that $H_1$ is true since we do not have control over what is happening when neither $H_0$ or $H_1$ is true...

I have the impression that we have to suppose that at least one between $H_0$ or $H_1$ is true, that is the experimentalist must have an idea at the beginning of all the possible models that could be true (e.g. if $H_1$ is the negation of $H_0$ this is trivially satisfied...)... Am I reasoning well?

Comment: That is a $\Huge\mbox{HUGE}$ wall of text...

Comment: Thanks ! I added spacing and highlightened the question to make it more readbale.

Comment: The two hypotheses must complement each other and be exhaustive. ie one of them is true and the other false.

Comment: (a) In _many_ books $\beta$ is used for the probability $P(R^c|H_1)$ and so power is defined as $\pi = 1 - \beta.$ In that case the goal is to make both 'error probabilities' $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as small as possible. (b) If the null hypothesis is $UNIF(0,1)$ and the alternative is $UNIF(1,2).$ you can be sure of a correct decision--and with only one observation. (c) There are 'multiple decision' frameworks in which the goal is to choose among several $H_i$'s that are exhaustive and mutually exclusive. Then, of course, @theoGR's Comment does not apply.

Comment: You are right for point (a). The standard notation for the power is $1-\beta$ and $\beta$ is called the sentitivity. I change immediately thanks a lot! I do not understand point (b) though, What do you want to say providing just a particular example? With point (c) do you want to say that in general for having a reasonable test the $H_i$ must be exhasutive and mutually exclusive?

Comment: @Bruce I didn't say that you cannot have multiple $H_i$'s . I said that  when you have two hypotheses  they  must partition the parameter space into two disjoint sets ie  complementary and exhaustive.

Comment: Actually regarding point (b) why do you say that we can be sure of making a correct decision? For example if we get $x=1.5$ we know that $H_0$ is false, but maybe the distribution is $UNIF(-1,1)$, not equal either to $H_0$ or $H_1$. To say that $H_1$ is true from this observation we need to know that either $H_0$ or $H_1$ models our data... I think this example exemplifies perfectly my doubt...

Comment: Ok $UNIF(-1,1)$ cannot be with that observation, but $UNIF(-2,2)$ shows my reasoning :)

Comment: (1) @theoGR. I had hoped to make it clear that I was adding to what you said, not disagreeing. (2) In my previous (b), there is the assumption that null and alternative are exhaustive and mutually exclusive.

Comment: I think this hypothesis could be formulated  as follows. Assume  $X\sim U(\theta,\theta+1)$  and we test  $H_0:\theta=0$ vs  $H_1:\theta=1$ . Reject if x in (1,2), accept if  x in (0,1). In this  case ,  type I error=0, power=1.

Comment: What I am asking: Is that a sensible rejection rule?. This is the only rule that   the correct decision will be made.